# How to specify directory used to evaluate makefile targets?

Tags: gnu-make

I am writing a gnu make file to build and run C++ unit tests.  I have the makefile put its .o files in the same directory that holds the make file.

We have a different set of makefiles used to build our products for delivery.  Those makefiles puts each .o file in the same directory that has the corresponding C++ source file.

My unit test makefile defines its .o target as "%.o: %.cpp".  In that makefile, I define VPATH to have the location of the .cpp files.  In addition, my unit test compilation command generates and uses .d files using the g++ MMD and MP options.

So here is the problem I am having.

I want my unit test makefile target to only evaluate the .o target by looking in my unit test makefile directory.

If the product delivery makefile already generated a .o out where the source file lives, I still want my unit test makefile to only consider its directory to determine if I need to rebuild the .o file.

However, that's not happening.  If a product delivery makefile had already put a .o where the source code lives, the unit test makefile sees that .o, and it says that the .o does not need to be built.

Is there a way for me to force my unit test makefile to only consider the unit test make file directory when evaluating .o file targets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you saying that the `.o` file is found via your `VPATH` setting?

You can use pattern-specific `vpath` to restrict the lookup to specific types of files:

```
vpath %.cpp $(SRCDIR)
```

instead of setting the global `VPATH`

Comment: Yes!  That's exactly what I needed.  Thanks!